# Где хранится кэш COM компонента Shockwave Flash Object

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, flash-player

Куда Shockwave Flash Object сохраняет кэш-файлы? И как их очистить?
По всей видимости место хранения отличается от стандартного плагина Flash или самостоятельного Standalone Flash Player, и кэш находится не в IE